# Check existing user node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

So i have the following query to check if the user exists in the database

```
connectDB.query("SELECT ACCOUNT_ID FROM registration WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = '"+ userAccnt +"'", function(err, result, field){
     if(result.lenght === 0){
        //new user logic
}else{  
    //existing user, redirect to another page 
 }
        }
```

So i still hit the new user logic every time even when the userAccnt value exists in the database? Could someone point out if i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i figured out where i was going wrong, my usrAccnt variable was being read in as string rather that an integer hence the query was probably failing. ACCOUNT_ID in my database is set to an INT type

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is extremely susceptible to SQL Injection. If someone is reading this post in the future, please be careful.

Also, here is the correct code for achieving this:

```
connectDB.query("SELECT ACCOUNT_ID FROM registration WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = ?, [userAccnt], function(err, result, field)

{
     if(result[0].length === 0){
        //new user logic
}

else{  
    //existing user, redirect to another page 

}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).